# In a button click i want to work like two backpress

Tags: android, button, onbackpressed

i have 3 activitys FirstActivity,SecondActivity,ThridActivity respectively, i put "intent" FirstActivity to SecondActivity , SecondActivity to ThridActivity.

Now if i click the backButton {onBackPressed()} on ThridActivity i want to go to the FirstActivity.

but i don't need 'Intent' to FirstActivity in 'onBackPressed()', i need two backpress code.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
            this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
}
```

these codes are working only single backpress.

Comment: `finish()` the second `Activity` when you start the third `Activity`.

Comment: You can achieve it in many ways: 1. Starting your activities with `startActvityForResult` and cascade close them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android. You can use different `launchMode`s defined in manifest https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe or use `LocalBoradcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks, The first one works fine @MikeM.

Comment: Do you mean that you need double click functinality?  to move from C->A without going to Actiivity B ?

Answer (score 0):

You may follow below flow for same:

1. Start SecondActvity from FirstActivity. At the same time finish the SecondActivity.
   like this:

   startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));

   finish();
2. Now when you press back one time from ThirdActivity, directly navigate to the FirstActivity

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the instance of `Second activity` when you are going from second to third activity.

But don't clear the instance of FirstActivity. If u will clear the `firstactivity` instace by clicking back from third it will close completly.

Code :

On FirstActivity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
```

On Second Activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class));
finish();
```

On ThirdActivity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
            this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
}
```

Hope that helps you.If its working doesn't forget to make it as the correct answer.